# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.newrelic.agent.android.tracing.TraceMachine.completeActivityTrace()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, newrelic

When debugging my app I see this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.newrelic.agent.android.tracing.TraceMachine.completeActivityTrace()' on a null object reference
```

I'm using:

```
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.5.0'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.5.0'
```

on my gradle files.

It is thrown by New Relic, I do not instantiate their classes or methods directly. It happens randomly, the app doesn't crash, but it shows in LogCat when I'm debugging. I can't find the reason on Google nor New Relic's docs.

Comment: it's just another `NPE`

Comment: There should be more error lines underneath that one. They'll tell you where it's trying to use the uninstantiated variable/object.